# Where can I get i915_error_state from debugfs and the full dmesg?

Tags: xorg, dmesg

My system has been intermittently freezing (apart from the cursor) for a month or two. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Dell XPS L502X (hybrid graphics card, so I'm running Bumblebee). Usually even SysReq + REISUB won't reboot it, and I have to hard reboot.

This last time I actually wasn't forced to reboot and got a TTY up. I got the following from the end of `less /var/log/Xorg.0.log` http://pastebin.com/fiwPay30 . Upon returning to TTY 7, I was kicked out to the login screen.

The log asks "Detected a hung GPU, disabling acceleration. When reporting this, please include i915_error_state from debugfs and the full dmesg."

How can I do this?

Comment: A colleague has suggested my original issue may be https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/515246 - still investigating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have mounted as so -

sudo mount -t debugfs debugfs /sys/kernel/debug

Taken from Intel's forum post here:

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/documentation/collecting-gpu-state-hangs-0

Good luck with finding a resolution.

Comment: To get dmesg, use `dmesg >> dmesg.txt`